# When the Omegawolf attacks a target that is guarded by the Huntsman, which of the three (Omegawolf, target, Huntsman) die?

Tags: werewolv.es

The Omegawolf usually can't be killed at night; does that apply to this situation, and what happens to the target and the Huntsman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. The Omegawolf won't be killed in this situation as they are immune to the kill.

The Huntsman will still sacrifice themselves though, and the target will remain alive - so in this situation only the Huntsman will die.

Comment: What if both a protector and a huntsman are visiting when the Alphawolf visits; which of those visitors (protector and/or huntsman) dies then?

Comment: As per https://werewolv.es/guides/roles/Huntsman - The huntsman triggers first, so the behaviour is the same as if the Protector didn't visit. (Huntsman dies, and tries (either successfully or not) to kill any visiting wolf)

Comment: Yeah, I messed up my follow-up question, I meant to say "when the Omegawolf visits"

Answer (score -1):

> What if both a protector and a huntsman are visiting when the Alphawolf visits; which of those visitors (protector and/or huntsman) dies then?

I assume you mean Omegawolf here? If so, both the Protector and the Huntsman die. If a Protector and a Huntsman guard the same target, the Huntsman's protection triggers first. The Protector dies for visiting the target that the Omegawolf attacked (Unless that target is the Protector, in which case the Protector survives).

Comment: Ah yeah, meant Omegawolf, thanks.